# How can i globally mock lodash/deep function in jest

Tags: jestjs, lodash

I am using lodash/deep function in the controller. While performing jest test for the controller it gives the following error:
All of the lodash functions gives errors.

> TypeError: cloneDeep_1.default is not a function.

sample code below

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'

static transformBoardBasicInfo (rawBoard:any): any {
    const clonedBoard: any = cloneDeep(rawBoard) as any
    clonedBoard.info = this.getInfo(rawBoard)
    return clonedBoard
}
```

Comment: Provide the code you want to test and you tried.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Please find the sample code and provide the solution. I find the same issue with all of the **lodash** functions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to add a spy on `cloneDeep` function. But it's unnecessary, `cloneDeep` function is a pure function and doesn't call any side-effected external services. So you don't need to mock or make a stub for it.

`index.ts`:

```js
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

export class SomeClass {
  public static transformBoardBasicInfo(rawBoard: any): any {
    const clonedBoard: any = cloneDeep(rawBoard) as any;
    clonedBoard.info = this.getInfo(rawBoard);
    return clonedBoard;
  }

  public static getInfo(board) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { SomeClass } from './';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

jest.mock('lodash/cloneDeep', () => jest.fn());

describe('main', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(SomeClass, 'getInfo');
    (cloneDeep as any).mockImplementationOnce((data) => {
      return require.requireActual('lodash/cloneDeep')(data);
    });
    const mRawBoard = { info: '123' };
    const actual = SomeClass.transformBoardBasicInfo(mRawBoard);
    expect(actual).toEqual({ info: '' });
    expect(cloneDeep).toBeCalledWith(mRawBoard);
    expect(SomeClass.getInfo).toBeCalledWith(mRawBoard);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59298693/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ should pass (25ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.075s, estimated 12s
```

Comment: I get the below error when i ran the above sample code.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockImplementationOnce' of undefined

 `(cloneDeep as any).mockImplementationOnce((data) => {
               return require.requireActual('lodash/cloneDeep')(data);
        });`